# how make when i click to textbox open a menu and after click the choise transfer value to textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a script where after I click an input field, a dropdown appears and when I click one of the options the value from the select dropdown populates in the input.

I have been able to open the select dropdown when I click on the input field, but I have transferred the value of the select to the input afterword.  What am I doing wrong?

HTML code here:

```
<form>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Width:<div id="text1"><input type="text" ></div></th>
        <th>heigth:<div id="text2"><input type="text" ></div></th> 
        <th>        
            <select id="vSelect" onclick="myFunction()" multiple style="height:100px;">
                <option value="sval1" >1</option>
                <option value="sval2">2</option>
                <option value="sval3">3</option>
                <option value="sval4">4</option>
                <option value="sval5">5</option>
            </select>
            <select id="vSelect1" onclick="myFunction1()" multiple style="height:100px;">
                <option value="sval6" >6</option>
                <option value="sval7">7</option>
                <option value="sval8">8</option>
                <option value="sval9">9</option>
                <option value="sval10">10</option>
            </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

javascript here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#text1').click(function(){
    $('#vSelect1').hide();  
    $('#vSelect').show();
});


$('#text2').click(function(){
    $('#vSelect').hide(); 
    $('#vSelect1').show();
});
```

});

```
function myFunction() {//bazei timi sto pedio text
    var sel = document.getElementById('vSelect');
    document.getElementById('text1').value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}

function myFunction1() {//bazei timi sto pedio text
    var sel = document.getElementById('vSelect1');
    document.getElementById('text2').value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

css here:

```
#vSelect{display:none;}
#vSelect1{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your event to onchange

```
<select id="vSelect1" onchange="myFunction1()" multiple style="height:100px;">
    <option value="sval6" >6</option>
    <option value="sval7">7</option>
    <option value="sval8">8</option>
    <option value="sval9">9</option>
    <option value="sval10">10</option>
</select>
```

if you use jquery it can be too simple like this

```
<select id="vSelect1" onchange="$('#text2').val($(this).val());$(this).hide();" multiple style="height:100px;">
    <option value="sval6" >6</option>
    <option value="sval7">7</option>
    <option value="sval8">8</option>
    <option value="sval9">9</option>
    <option value="sval10">10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well, all jQuery

Changing the id to be on the input field rather than the div:

```
<form>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Width:<div><input id="text1" type="text" ></div></th>
        <th>heigth:<div><input id="text2" type="text" ></div></th> 
        <th>        
            <select id="vSelect" onclick="myFunction()" multiple style="height:100px;">
                <option value="sval1" >1</option>
                <option value="sval2">2</option>
                <option value="sval3">3</option>
                <option value="sval4">4</option>
                <option value="sval5">5</option>
            </select>
            <select id="vSelect1" onclick="myFunction1()" multiple style="height:100px;">
                <option value="sval6" >6</option>
                <option value="sval7">7</option>
                <option value="sval8">8</option>
                <option value="sval9">9</option>
                <option value="sval10">10</option>
            </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Javascript without need of functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#text1').focus(function(){
        $('#vSelect1').hide();  
        $('#vSelect').show();
    });


    $('#text2').click(function(){
        $('#vSelect').hide(); 
        $('#vSelect1').show();
    });

    $('#vSelect').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#text1').val(val);
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('#vSelect1').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#text2').val(val);
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```